# How to enable PHP class suggestion in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-5.3

I just started using Visual Studio Code editor. But class suggestion is not showing for me. How can I enable this feature? I tried it by installing PHP IntelliSense extension but not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this extension for PHP. It's working well for me.

[PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)

Comment: Unfortunately this is now a Premium feature that requires a license. (Yea I know it's 6 years later, but this thread still pops up in Google).

Comment: reality is we have pay and use if no choice :)

Answer (score 0):

Install PHP Namespace Resolver Extension. it works exactly same like PhpStorm.